# Stemmer (взятие корня слова) для русского языка?

Tags: python, естественный-язык, nlp

Нужна библиотека для выделение корня со слов. 
Сейчас использую SnowballStemmer с библиотеки NTLK (www.nltk.org/). К сожалению, есть очень много вариантов, где корень определяется не верно.

Возможно, можно поставить какие-то словари для NTLK? Или есть другие библиотеки (алгоритмы)?

Хочу получить совет от людей, которые имели с этим дело. Интересуют реализации на Python ну или наличие способов подружить с Python.

Спасибо)

Comment: *"есть очень много вариантов, где корень определяется не верно."* Чтобы вопрос был менее общим, не могли вы пример кода показать, что вы ожидали получить (правильные корни) и что код вместо этого выводит.

Comment: Стемминг и не должен возвращать корень. Если повезет, то основа (то, что и возвращает операция) совпадает, но это необязательно.

Comment: Что Вы использовали? Какие проблема возникли?

Comment: Если "Стемминг и не должен возвращать корень", тогда какие есть варианты получить результат максимально близок к корню кроме стемминга?